# How hang up these hook-less curtains, without modifying condo interior?

Tags: discussion

I edited [How can I hook curtains to vertical blinds?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/197174). Pls re-open? I don't think you need more details or clarity because [brhans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/197438/how-hang-up-these-hook-less-curtains-without-modifying-condo-interior?noredirect=1#comment354236_197438) understood and answered my question!

> I've never known the proper name until now when I started googling the description. I found that they're called "[Pleater Hooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=pleater+hooks)" or "[Drapery Hooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=drapery+hooks)". You use them by gathering together 4 of the pockets in the top hem of the curtain and pushing one 'prong' of the hook into each pocket, which then hold them together forming 'pleats' in the top of the curtain. Then each hook has a hook on the back to hook onto a [Curtain Ring](https://www.google.com/search?q=curtain+rings), which slides on the pole. – [brhans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/33897/brhans) [Jul 13 at 11:50](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/197438/how-hang-up-these-hook-less-curtains-without-modifying-condo-interior?noredirect=1#comment354236_197438)